# Change the tenant url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, tenant

I have the SharePoint online like `Company123.Sharepoint.com`. I want the URL to be `Company.Sharepoint.com`.

What is the best way to change the URL?

Reagrds,
Divakar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible, your only option is to create a new tenant. You can give your vote for this to be implemented here: 
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/10285887-make-is-possible-to-change-tenant-name-in-office36

Comment: Is it possible to have a 'Sharepoint.company.com' instead of 'company.sharepoint.com'?

Comment: No, SharePoint Online only comes with <tenant>.sharepoint.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** to change the tenant URL.

> Unfortunately, it isn't possible to change the SharePoint domain name for your organization in Office 365. For example, if the name of your organization changes from "Contoso" to "Fourth Coffee," you can't change `contoso.sharepoint.com` to `fourthcoffee.sharepoint.com`.
>
> To use the domain name `fourthcoffee.sharepoint.com`, **you would need to purchase a new Office 365 subscription and move all email, files, and any other data you want to keep to the new subscription**.

**Source**: [Change your SharePoint domain name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-your-sharepoint-domain-name).

**Similar UserVoice**: [change tenant name/url](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/312601-m365-microsoft-365-admin-mobile/suggestions/33484381-change-tenant-name-url).